# Android : dialog and NullPointerException

Tags: android, dialog

I have the first activity that call a dialog from second activity with this code :

```
public class negozi extends ListActivity implements dati_punti{

    private Context context;
    private popup_segnala segnala;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.negozi);
        context = this;
                    visual_pop(context);
          }
          public void visual_pop(Context context){
                  segnala = new popup_segnala(context);
                   segnala.showDialog(popup_segnala.OK_INSERT);
          }
```

the second activity, popup_segnala have this code :

```
public class popup_segnala extends Activity {
public static final int OK_INSERT = 1;
private static Context context;

public popup_segnala(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
   switch(id){
   case OK_INSERT :
        Builder build_insert = createDialog(context,"Dati registrati correttamente. Grazie","Alert");
        build_insert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

             @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
           }
             });
      return build_insert.show();       
     }
    return null;
 }
}
```

Why ??? :-(
I have this error log:

> 09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657): 09-06 19:44:35.507:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-06 19:44:35.507:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657): **java.lang.NullPointerException** 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.Activity.getVolumeControlStream(Activity.java:3703) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.setOwnerActivity(Dialog.java:188) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:2491) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:2515) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2565) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   it.android.infoconsumatori.negozi.onOptionsItemSelected(negozi.java:65)
>   09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:774)
>   09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
>   09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
>   09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
>   09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
>   09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152) 09-06 19:44:35.507:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-06 19:44:35.507:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-06 19:44:35.507:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   09-06 19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 09-06
>   19:44:35.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1657):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You should read through the tutorials posted on the developer site. It's clear that you're missing the fundamentals of how the android framework works. You should never be calling `new` on a class that extends `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you create the class popup_segnala that extends Activity? You have to move onCreateDialog(int id) code in your main activity where you will simply call showDialog(OK_INSERT).

Moreover onCreateDialog must return a dialog object.