# Android : Call Dialog from other activity

Tags: android

It's possibile to start a dialog from other activity ?

Comment: What do you mean "other activity"?  That's a bit vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think so, and if it is you shouldn't.  Each dialog should be created in the context of the current activity.  For what reason do you want to do this?

If your doing it because you want to save code, it makes much more sense to create a new class called something like DialogFactory.  Then you can have a static method that takes a context as a parameter and creates a dialog.  This way you can just call

```
Dialog myDialog = DialogFactory.createDialog(this);
```

any time you need to use that dialog.

Heres an example of what createDialog() could look like

```
public static Dialog createDialog(Context context){
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_view);
   //set your title, message, buttons etc.
   return dialog;
}
```

Comment: I have a dialog that can be started from many activity and I want to create one class of this dialog and call it from every activity

Comment: I updated my answer.  Should be exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: But this class must to extends Activity ?

Comment: nope. just has to import any dialog and any view classes that your using.  I haven't tested it exactly but I'm almost positive it should work.  If you can't figure it out, let me know.  I'll double check my solution and get back to you

Comment: Ok, but this code is wrong ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326182/android-dialog-and-nullpointerexception

Comment: Yea your doing a couple things wrong but mainly the fact that your creating an activity inside another activity.  I can't say for sure but I don't think that will work at all.  Also you don't have to use the onCreateDialog method unless you need the dialog to be tied to the activity (for volume control, etc).  And even then you can always accomplish this by using the setOwnerActivity(); method on the dialog.  Hope that makes some sense

Comment: If my answer worked for you, you should accept it.  It will make it more likely for people to answer you questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If will add the dialog code in any global class and pass the context as a parameter to display the dialog on each activity,in any activity if its displaying dialog and if ll change the orientation the dialog wont be visible, better to override and use OncreatDialog() for each activity.